# Finding family of functions for which $\Delta h = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplacian

I have a function $h(x, y) = g(r)$, with $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. I was able to find a formula for $\Delta h$:

$$\Delta h = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial \theta^2}$$

I need to prove that the family of functions for which $\Delta h = 0$ is only $h = c \log (r) + d$ where $c, d$ are constants. We just started doing Calc 3 in this class so I don't really know what tools I can use from here.

Comment: Assume $g(r,\theta) = R(r) \Theta (\theta)$ and apply it in $\Delta h = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Ummm, what you want to prove is not quite true.  It is true for the special case of $\partial_\theta g=0$.  But if $g$ is allowed to vary in $\theta$, nope.  So I would first assume $\partial_\theta g=0$.  Then demonstrate that your solution actually solves the "radial" part of the equation.  Then, since that part is a second order linear equation, it can have only two independent solutions.  You have two independent solutions ($c\log(r)$ and $d$), so they have to be the ones.

Comment: My bad, I mistyped. Above in the packet it says that $h(x,y) = g(r, \theta)$, but for this exercise it only wants $h(x,y) = g(r)$. Thanks for your answer - I'm reading through it now. Okay, so I've read through it and it makes sense. Funny that it uses tools from ODE since this course is taken before ODE. Anyhow, +1.